# Local Network URL Redirects

Tags: windows, webserver, windows-server-2008

Hi I have recently created a Server on a Local intranet running Windows Server 2008.

A Virtual server is running on the Windows Server and I know I can change Host files on my machine to point at for example 192.168.1.212

But what I would ideally like to do is have every computer on the network (intranet) getting redirected exactly the same as host file but without having to always update every computer.

I'm sure must be possible I was looking at IIS creating websites in there? But am unsure and do not want to mess around with something without really knowing what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to create a Host (A) record resolving the desired hostname to that IP address on whatever server is providing DNS for your network.